# default text in mediawiki new pages

Tags: templates, configuration, formatting, mediawiki

Does anyone know how to make mediawiki automatically populate a new page with some text when the edit button is clicked for the 1st time?  I have tried the MediaWiki:Newarticletext page but this only affects the text that is displayed when a user visits a page that doesn't exist.  I would like to provide my users the option of a pre-built template type page that doesn't require them to type in a lot of text that will be very similar on many new pages.

I don't think mediawiki templates are the way to go as they just imclude the text when the page is rendered and they don't provide the text for the user to customise.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [MultiBoilerplate](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aMultiBoilerplate)? You can se this to load default pages - and you can create multiple default. The only problem is that it won't load when you *create* the page but just after (you need to press **Load**).